# Manual registration of WebApi Controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I would like to disable the automatic discovery of controllers while self-hosting WebApi, and manually nominate controllers and associate them with routes at run time.

Filip W has a nice write-up on [customising controller discovery](https://www.strathweb.com/2013/08/customizing-controller-discovery-in-asp-net-web-api/) which leads me to believe that I could simply implement `IHttpControllerTypeResolver` or `IAssembliesResolver`to manipulate the automatic discovery into doing nothing, but this only solves half the problem, and it feels like a poor solution for the half of the problem it addresses - I want to effectively disable discovery; but this feels more like butchering discovery but keeping it around...?

Once discovery is disabled, I would like to compensate by nominating a controller (or controller factory?) that will be determined prior to the server initialisation. I could possibly handle the routing aspect with `IHttpControllerSelector` however I can't see how I am supposed to otherwise nominate a controller such that WebApi is aware of it for this to work.

In summary I want to:

- Disable controller discovery
- Specify controllers (instances, types, or factories) explicitly

What is the most appropriate method to achieve this (if any)?

I am not tied to specific versions of anything; currently using .Net framework 4.7.2 and `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OwinSelfHost` 5.2.6.

Comment: Might I ask what your actual intent is? Perhaps there is another way to achieve what you are trying to do without disabling auto controller discovery.

Comment: The intent is to support 3rd party integrations at a service level. I don't want these integrations to just provide controllers verbaitam. Their security model, routes, and authorisation to load at a module level must be vetter and managed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the HttpControllerSelector ist the right way to do this.
Here is a small example:

HttpControllerSelector:

```
public class HttpControllerSelector : IHttpControllerSelector
{
    private readonly HttpConfiguration _httpConfiguration;

    public HttpControllerSelector(HttpConfiguration httpConfiguration)
    {
        this._httpConfiguration = httpConfiguration;
    }

    public HttpControllerDescriptor SelectController(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        return new HttpControllerDescriptor(this._httpConfiguration, 
                                            nameof(ValuesController), 
                                            typeof(ValuesController));
    }

    public IDictionary<string, HttpControllerDescriptor> GetControllerMapping()
    {
        var mapping = new Dictionary<string, HttpControllerDescriptor>
        {
            {
                nameof(ValuesController),
                new HttpControllerDescriptor(this._httpConfiguration,
                                             nameof(ValuesController),
                                             typeof(ValuesController))
            }
        };
        return mapping;
    }
}
```

WebApiConfig:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services
        config.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpControllerSelector), new HttpControllerSelector(config));

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

So, in the HttpControllerSelector, you can do everything you want. As a simple example, there is a controller which one is always selected. At this point you can use a factory or something that suits you.

To disable the normal discovery, you have to override the normal Selector shown in the WebApiConfig.

Hope this gave your an idea how to do it, happy coding!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I realise that I can provide a factory via the `IHttpControllerTypeResolver`, and the article linked in the question describes the role of `IHttpControllerSelector`, however how can I be certain that Controllers will not be discovered dynamically and available within the pipeline in spite of the selector not nominating them? IE what is to stop some other internal component getting `IHttpControllerTypeResolver` via the service locator, and this then falling back on a set of reflected controllers? I was unable to determine this from the documentation.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no other point which resolves assemblies. But you can provide your own implementations for the TypeResolver as well. In case you don't know it, here is a link to the WebApi Poster (https://www.asp.net/media/4071077/aspnet-web-api-poster.pdf). On the right side you can see all extension point which can be overwritten.

Comment: That diagram is exactly what I needed! Thank you! I mustn't have looked hard enough for that - now I can't not find it! Problem solved.